# How to override a has_many association so it shows default values from a parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are three models: `Country`, `City` and `Plan`.

A plan can be associated to a country or a city. If the city has plans, then return those plans. If the city doesn't have plans, then return the city's country's plans.

For example:

`United_Kingdom` has three plans: `uk_default_1`, `uk_default_2`, `uk_default_3`.

`London` has two plans: `london_1`, `london_2`.

`Leeds` doesn't have associated plans.

`London` and `Leeds` belong to `United_Kingdom`.

I want to achieve:

```
London.plans # [london_1, london_2]
Leeds.plans # [uk_default_1, uk_default_2, uk_default_3]
```

I started defining the following relationships:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :plans
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :city
end
```

But I don't know how to go from here. How can I do this in the rails way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably just make and use a new method `active_plans` in the City model, which would return city plans if present, country plans if not...

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
  has_many :plans # added to support "country.plans in City model"
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :plans

  def active_plans
    return plans if plans.present?
    return country.plans
  end
end
```